# syntax error in from clause C# and Access

Tags: c#, sql, database

I keep getting this run time error, `syntax error in from clause`. I tried already using my sql query in access and it seems ok.

Here's my code and I am using C# windows form with text box and button

```
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Misry27\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Inventory\Inventory\bin\Debug\Inventory.mdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Employee where username = '" + this.tbUsername.Text + "' and password = '" + this.tbPassword.Text + "';", conn);
            OleDbDataReader dr;
            conn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is correct");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Incorrect");
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: And adding at all the rest. PASSWORD is a reserved keyword in MS-Access. When used from NET you need to put square brackets around it

Comment: In the first line you have `new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4);`, there is no `"` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments above, PASSWORD is a reserved keyword and need to be enclosed in square brackets when used in query executed from net.

The usual advice follows. Use parameterized query to avoid parsing problem and sql injections, use the using statement around your disposable objects.

```
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(a correct connection string here))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"select * from Employee 
                                            where username = ? AND [Password] = ?", conn);
{

    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", this.tbUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", this.tbPassword.Text);
    using(OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       .....
    }
}
```